# Undefined index if the array

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using following function to get the options stored in wordpress.

```
function get_settings( $option ) {
    $options = get_option( 'my_options', my_default_options() );
    return $options[ $option ];
}
```

In the above function `my_default_options()` returns an array which has default values. Now if I call the above function like: 
`get_settings("title");` it will work fine if the "title" exists in the default options array.

However if `title` does not exist in the default options array, then I get the following warning:

```
Notice: Undefined index:
```

How can I fix this notice? I tried following:

```
function get_settings( $option ) {
    $defaults = my_default_options();

    if(in_array($option, $defaults)){
        $options = get_option( 'my_options', my_default_options() );
        return $options[ $option ];
    }
}
```

But it still returns same notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure if it exists or not using `isset`

```
function get_settings( $option ) {
    $defaults = my_default_options();

    if(in_array($option, $defaults)){
        $options = get_option( 'my_options', my_default_options() );
        return isset($options[ $option ]) ?  $options[ $option ] : '';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the function `array_key_exists`. `in_array` search for value while `array_key_exists` search for keys/indexes :

```
function get_settings( $option ) {
    $options = get_option( 'my_options', my_default_options() );
    if(array_key_exists($option, $options))
        return $options[ $option ];
    return "unknown";
}
```